# Pegar atributo de elemento carregado dinamicamente sem evento click

Tags: jquery

Durante o carregamento da página eu pego dados do BD e crio uma lista conforme abaixo.

```
function chatContactList()  {
    $.post('src/inc/chat/', { DataProcess:'chatContactListShow' }, function(data){
        switch(data.status) {
            case 'error':
                sNoty(data.message, null, 'error', null);   
                break;
            case 'noHasList':
                return false;
                break;
            case 'hasList': 
                var content = ''
                $.each(data.chatOBJ, function(index, value){
                    content += '<li>';
                    content += '    <a href="#" data-process-id="'+value.pr_id+'" id="chatByContact" class="chatByContact">'+value.userName+'<i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>';                   
                    content += '</li>';
                });
                $("#ulSidebarMenuContact").html(content);   
                break;
            case 'logOut': 
            case 'reload':  
                window.location.reload();
                break;      
        }           
    }, 'json');         
};
```

Após a carga dos dados e criar a lista, eu preciso pegar o atributo data-process-id, sem evento click, e fazer constante atualização, mas não pego nenhum atributo.

```
function updateMessageNotRead()
{   
    var prIdArray = new Array();

    $('a[id="chatByContact"]').each(function()  { 
        prIdArray.push($(this).attr('data-process-id'));
    }); 

    ...
}
```

Como pegar este atributo criado automaticamente e sem delegar em evento como o click?

Comment: essa função tem que ser executada dentro da função de retorno que cria a lista

Comment: Problema é que preciso atualizar periodicamente, se existe mensagem referente a este contato usando a informação da li

Comment: e como vc pretende fazer essa atualização periodica? setInterval?

Comment: Definir com setinterval

Comment: Mas vai ser no mesmo esquema, vai rodar o setInterval no retorno da função

Comment: Tenho 2 funções, a primeira que gera a lista de contato de chat, quando a função recebe o JSON, gera a li.. Você diz que quando acabar de gerar a li eu já chamo a função para atualizar as mensagens?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77535/discussion-between-wees-smith-and-rrv).

Comment: Wees, Acabei de chamar a função para verificar a mensagem, e defini o setinterval, e funcionou com sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Minha primeira sugestão seria utilizar classe nesses elementos que deseja pegar ao invés de id.
Na maioria do meus projetos quando tenho uma lista dinâmica e necessito realizar alguma ação nos mesmos utilizamos classe especificas no elementos.

Pelo que entendi após carregar a pagina html você deseja pegar o atributo separado de cada elemento gerado dinamicamente para realizar alguma tarefa, no exemplo anexado coloquei apenas um console.log para mostrar o valor do atributo.

Vou te dar um exemplo utilizando uma sequencia de check-box que seria gerados.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    getElements();
});
function getElements() {
    var prIdArray = new Array();
  $( ".elementoData" ).each(function() {
    var DataValue = $(this).attr("data-process-id");
    prIdArray.push(DataValue);
  });
  console.log("Array criado : ");
  console.log(prIdArray);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <ol>
         <li>
            <a href="#" class="elementoData" data-process-id="01" id="chatByContact" class="chatByContact">Igor 1<i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>';
         </li>
         <li> <a href="#" class="elementoData" data-process-id="97" id="chatByContact" class="chatByContact">Igor<i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>';</li>
         <li> <a class="elementoData" href="#" data-process-id="98" id="chatByContact" class="chatByContact">Pedro<i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>';</li>
         <li><a class="elementoData" href="#" data-process-id="99" id="chatByContact" class="chatByContact">henrique<i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a>';</li>
      </ol>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por desencargo eu coloquei uma classe e mudei a função, mas continua não pegando os atributos. Crie o li com estático e a função updateMessageNotRead retorna os atributos. Quando usamos um evento, fica fácil delegar com algo do tipo '$('.div-content').on('click', '.elementoData', function(event) { '.. Estou procurando para ver se existe um modo de delegar sem evento.

Comment: Poderia postar por favor um exemplo do seu html ?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta e inserir o JQuery onde insiro o li na ul que já existia no DOM

Comment: Editei meu exemplo de código para considerar o elementos <a> e <li> conforme seu código gera. Consegui obter os atributos do mesmo jeito.Quando seu documento terminar de ser gerado você chama a função para dar get nesse atributos

Comment: Igor.. Acabei de chamar a função para verificar a mensagem, e defini o setinterval, e funcionou com sucesso.